# Simple JavaScript Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a simple drop down menu from a menu button (not actually a button). I know I have done this before and have referenced the project the I previously completed and have everything exactly the same and it still will not work. Any help would be appreciated! I have a the most current **jQuery UI** referenced in my **HTML** head.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div id='logo_container'>
        <img src='img/rinTin_logo_white.png' id='header_logo' alt='RinTin Logo' />
    </div>
    <div id='menu_button_container'>
        <a href='#' id='menu_button_link'><img src='img/menu_button.png' id='menu_button' alt='' /></a>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
    <div id='mobile_nav_container'>
        <nav id='mobile_nav'>
            <ul id="primary_mobile">
                <li><a href='#'>Schedule</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Users</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Shifts</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>System</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Forums</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="secondary_mobile">
                <li><a href='#'>My Account</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Help</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
#mobile_nav_container{
    display:none;
}'
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mobile_nav_container').removeClass('hidden');
});

$().ready(function(){
    $('#menu_button_link').click(function(){
        $('#mobile_nav_container').show('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: First question: why are you making this using javascript, instead of just using HTML and CSS?

Comment: What exactly isn't working about your solution? What have you tried to do that might fix the problem?

Comment: @MikeC I am able to hide the navigation list upon the page load, however, once the menu button (div) is clicked the menu will not display or "show".

Comment: "have everything exactly the same and it still will not work". Clearly, you haven't. If everything is exactly the same, then it would work. Computers are not random in that way. You just need to find the difference. There will be some extra code included that overrides something, or some important code not included, or similarly with some library or other. Or you made a typo, or whatever.